# Add executable to Path

Tags: 14.04, paths, .profile

I know this question has been asked a hundred times but for some reason all the answers aren't working on my system.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

I'm trying to add the file `activator` to my PATH so that I can launch it from any directory.

`activator` sits in `/opt/activator-dist-1.3.5/`

However, I've tried adding all sorts of lines to `.profile`, but none of them seem to work - when I try and call `activator` elsewhere, I just get an error.

What exactly should I be adding?

---

Neither of these work:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/activator-dist-1.3.5

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/activator-dist-1.3.5/activator/
```

Comment: Are you sourcing `.profile` when you're done? Show us what you've added so we can show you what you did wrong.

Comment: @ElefantPhace - I've edited my answer. What do you mean by sourcing?

Comment: Try putting quotes around it. And then in a terminal `source .profile` then try to run it

Comment: Should I put quotes around the entire line? EDIT: `source .profile` made it work! thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/activator-dist-1.3.5"
```

Open a terminal and type `source .profile`

Then type `activator`